# Roll Up Fields On Table in VF PAge

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I want to Display in roll up data in table of visualforce page. 
Scenarios:

1. Table contain list of account types and every account have multiple fields.
2. want to rollup every account types fields and display in table.

for examaple:- like their is 3 eduction type account and every account have some balance, high credit, paydue etc. i want to rollup their balance, high credit, paydue and display in table.

[image: Example of table what i want]

in this table education type account is 3 and every account have some balance like 100, 50 150 and their rollup is 300 which is display in table like that every row cell are rollup of fields.

I hope m well defined the Scenarios.

to full fill that senarios i approach in that way:

this is my controller class code:

```
public AggregateResult[] result;

result = [SELECT Credit_Loan_Type__c type,COUNT(id) num,SUM(Account_Balance__c) totalBalance,SUM(High_Credit_Amount__c) highCredit,
                      SUM(Monthly_Payment__c) monthlyPayment,SUM(Past_Due_Amount__c) dueAmount FROM Trade_Accounts__c 
                      Where Personal_Credit_Report__r.Contact__c =:conId
                      GROUP BY Credit_Loan_Type__c ];

 Map<String,String> typs = new Map<String,String>();
        typs.put('MORTGAGE', 'MORTGAGE');
        typs.put('AUTO', 'AUTO');
        typs.put('EDUCATION', 'EDUCATION');
        typs.put('INSTALLMENT', 'OTHER INSTALLMENT');
        typs.put('OPEN', 'OPEN');
        typs.put('CreditCard', 'REVOLVING');
        typs.put('OTHER', 'OTHER');



        reportList= new List<WrappperReport>();
        for(AggregateResult agr : result){
            System.debug('agr+++=='+agr);
        for(string ids : typs.keySet()){
           System.debug('idss+=='+ids);
               WrappperReport  wrp = new WrappperReport();
                if(agr.get('type') == ids ){ 
                    wrp.typeo = typs.get(ids);
                    wrp.count = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('num'));
                   wrp.balance = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('totalBalance'));
                   wrp.highCredit = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('highCredit'));
                   wrp.payment = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('monthlyPayment'));
                   wrp.pastDue = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('dueAmount'));
                   reportList.add(wrp);                   
                }else{
                    wrp.typeo = typs.get(ids);
                    wrp.count = 0;
                    wrp.balance = 0;
                    wrp.highCredit = 0;
                    wrp.payment = 0;
                    wrp.pastDue = 0;
                    reportList.add(wrp);
                }

public class WrappperReport{
        public string typeo {get;set;}
        public Integer count {get;set;}
        public Integer balance {get;set;}
        public Integer highCredit {get;set;}
        public Integer payment {get;set;}
        public Integer pastDue {get;set;}

    }
```

and this is my vf page code to display that table:

```
 <tbody>

                <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:repeat value="{!reportList}" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td>{!item.typeo}</td>
                <td>{!item.count}</td>
                <td>{!item.balance}</td>
                <td>{!item.highCredit}</td>
                <td>{!item.payment}</td>                
                <td>{!item.pastDue}</td>              
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
   </apex:pageBlock>  
            </tbody>
```

its working fine for single type of account but if added different types of account then table create multiple times for every types

[image: output of my code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your if-else part that's causing the problem. Essentially, you're adding each type for every queried type, causing a multiplicative effect. Instead, consider using a Map instead. What we'll do here is initialize all values to 0, then populate them from the result set. This means that you won't get the multiplicative effect you're seeing here.

---

```
Map<String, WrapperReport> output = new Map<String, WrapperReport>();
for(String ids: typs.keySet()) {
  WrapperReport wrapper = new WrapperReport();
  wrapper.typeo = typs.get(ids);
  wrapper.count = 0;
  wrapper.balance = 0;
  wrapper.highCredit = 0;
  wrapper.payment = 0;
  wrapper.pastdue = 0;
  output.put(ids, wrapper);
}
for(AggregateResult agr : result){
   WrapperReport wrp = output.get((String)agr.get('type'));
   wrp.count = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('num'));
   wrp.balance = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('totalBalance'));
   wrp.highCredit = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('highCredit'));
   wrp.payment = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('monthlyPayment'));
   wrp.pastDue = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('dueAmount'));
}
reportList = output.values();
```

Comment: thanxx for reply... But When i tried like this way then i always getting Attempt to de-reference a null object  error. I tried 
this way but still getting same error

Comment: if((Decimal)agr.get('num') !=Null) wrp.count = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('num')); else wrp.count = 0;
 if((Decimal)agr.get('totalBalance') >0) wrp.balance = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('totalBalance')); else  wrp.balance = 0;
                    if((Decimal)agr.get('highCredit') >0) wrp.highCredit = Integer.valueOf((Decimal)agr.get('highCredit')); else wrp.highCredit = 0;

Comment: @sanukumarverma It's a case-sensitivity issue then. Make sure the case for each value matches a valid Credit Loan Type value.

Comment: @sanukumarverma That's all unnecessary code. And probably wrong code anyways; if totalBalance is null, you will get a NullPointerException checking totalBalance > 0.

Comment: thnxx now its working...thnxx for help